# at=info method=GET path="/api/users?username=Aman" host=soshial.herokuapp.com dyno=web.1 connect=0ms status=500

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, nodejs-server, heroku-api

I am using the nodeJS server which I have deployed on Heroku and it is working fine on the homepage("/") but it's not working when I requested the URL("/api/users").

When I am requesting data from the server these errors occur

[Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxYxh.png)

Here is the Code which is in my index.js

[index.js Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9C3L.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Is it working correctly on your localhost ? If your answer is true you can change the content of the route that is wrong with the basic structure like _res.status(400)_. Because the error is your codes or heroku. You have to know it firstly.